# Debugging ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-click, ui-select

I'm experiencing trouble with an angular-ui plugin (ui-select): for some reason, I cannot select any option.

Looking in dev tools and changing the `ng-click` attribute for the relevant DOM element to `alert('test');` doesn't result in the alert being called either. This leads me to believe `ng-click` isn't being called for some reason.

Anyway, since I cannot find any information on this and I'm suspecting there might be a compatibility issue with another plugin or library.  I'm wondering if there is any way that I can debug `ng-click` operations. I'd like to be able to pinpoint where in the event chain things go wrong.

Comment: [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) might be what you need.

Comment: @Blazemonger I'm already using Batarang. I'm no expert with it, but I did check if the element that should call $select.select() has access to the right scope. Batarang says it does. I'm not sure how it could help me in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very useful post related to this post regarding [why angular fails silently on errors in expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297108/angularjs-ng-click-silently-eats-errors#21297349)

The work flow I have found to work for me is to first double check that your controller method or function that you are calling exists in your current scope.  This can be a pain to debug, but often times I have found it's just a typo on my part.

I would start by putting `debugger` in the first line of that function or method and determining if your program haults there.

PS:
[another explanation for this behavior](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/angular/HRVOUKEHLFw)

Answer (score -3):

- Load Chrome to your web site.
- Press F12 for dev mode.
- Go to Sources.
- Set breakpoints in your JS files.

Comment: Where should I put breapoints? when I put one in the ui-select library (yes, I put it at the beginning of $select.select() (the method ng-click should call) ), but it doesn't break. That's why I'm looking for a way to debug the ng-click event chain in angular itself.

Comment: the vanilla "ng-change="doSomething()" for selects doesn't work with ui-select?

Comment: It should, but since I cannot select any options, the model isn't updated nor ng-change called.